# How can I connect EJB to Mule?

Tags: java, ejb, enterprise, mulesoft

We use an old system that uses EJB protocols. Transferring to the restful API is a big deal for us. Does anyone know how to connect EJB with [Mule](https://www.mulesoft.com/) without coding?

Comment: EJB has nothing to do with REST.  You could write a wrapper with an HTTP client that exposed a REST API and did EJB calls as its implementation.  Not possible without coding.  There is an EJB connector for Mulesoft: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/ejb-transport-reference

Answer (score 0):

There is no current EJB connector for Mule 4 to invoke EJBs without code. You could create Java client code to remotely invoke the EJB, encapsulate it into a custom connector and use it in your Mule applications.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this connector in the [Anypoint Exchange](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/com.plektonlabs.mulesoft.connectors/mule-ejb-connector/): . It is also certified by MuleSoft, so it might work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is an [EJB connector](https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/com.plektonlabs.mulesoft.connectors/mule-ejb-connector/) in MuleSoft. But it only works for Mule 4.